# How to create location picker and search using mapbox?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, geolocation, mapbox

I want to create a location picker including the search field to focus on an area. So when the user doesn't know about the address, he can pick on the map or search the area first on the search field before picking the address on map.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, when the user picks the map's location, the `fetch` function will be triggered to get the address based on coordinate (lng,lat) as the parameter.

```html
<head>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.5.1/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css"
        type="text/css">
    <script
        src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.5.1/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 400px;height: 400px;"></div>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="address">
</body>
```

```html
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', //id element html
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        zoom: 9 // starting zoom
    });

    var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
        mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
        marker: false,
        zoom: 20
    });


    map.addControl(
        geocoder
    );

    let marker = null
    map.on('click', function (e) {
        mapClickFn(e.lngLat);

        if (marker == null) {
            marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
                .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
                .addTo(map);
        } else {
            marker.setLngLat(e.lngLat)
        }
    });



    function mapClickFn(coordinates) {
        const url =
            "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/" +
            coordinates.lng +
            "," +
            coordinates.lat +
            ".json?access_token=" +
            mapboxgl.accessToken

        fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then((data) => {
            if (data.features.length > 0) {
                const address = data.features[0].place_name;
                document.getElementById("coordinate").value = address;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("coordinate").value = "No address found";
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```